# Prevent sourcing a bash script, in the script itself

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

At the top of a bash script, I have this:

```
if [[ "$npm_registry_override" != "yes" ]]; then
  echo "refusing to source npm.sh script because env is not set."
  exit 0;
fi
```

the problem is that when I source it and the env var is not set, my terminal window simply closes.

if I do this instead:

```
 if [[ "$npm_registry_override" != "yes" ]]; then
      echo "refusing to source npm.sh script because env is not set."
      return 0;
 fi
```

I get an error/warning saying cannot return unless within a bash function.

So what are you suppose to do? The only thing I can think of is to wrap my entire script in the if statement.

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:bash], but it does not reflect Bash's behaviour for the `return` case ([which is documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-return)) - what gives?

Comment: maybe I am imagining things, but I swear bash complains sometimes when return is called outside the context of a function - but maybe return is ok when you are sourcing a script, just not when you are running it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the behaviour I see with `bash`. Nor is it what's documented in my version (4.4.12).

```
$ cat <<'x' >x.sh
echo "This is x.sh"
return 0
x
$ source x.sh
This is x.sh
$
```

The man page writes about the `return` verb:

> **`return [n]`** - [...] If `return` is used outside a function, but during execution of a script  by the  `.`  (`source`) command, it causes the shell to stop executing that script and return either `n` or the exit status of the last command executed within the script as the  exit  status  of  the script.

Comment: This is Bash's behaviour as far back as 3.1, probably further.

Comment: @MichaelHomer meaning this answer is correct?

Comment: @AlexanderMills you don't just have to take my word for it. I've provided some code that illustrates a working example for you to check in your own environment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @roaima ' s answer:
add this line early in your script.

```bash
return 0  2>/dev/null || :
```

- It works even after `set -e`
- It will not show an error message when not using `source`.
- It prevents running further lines if `source`ed. (But only quietly. Any solution for an error message in that case?)

Comment: Why not using a compound statement with `{ bla; bla; bla; }` to squeeze out an error message? After all `:` is a builtin shell function roughly equivalent to `true`. I think the `return` simply does what you'd expected from within a sourced context and `:` makes sure (your remark about `set -e`) that the error from it _when not sourced_ doesn't wreak havoc.

Comment: Do you mean `{ echo "error message"; return 0  2>/dev/null }`? Can you write that compound statement that you mean?

Comment: I was referring to the question in the third bullet point, yes. Something like what you wrote should technically do the trick. I'd probably write the error to `stderr`, but that's cosmetics.